# Changing the data type of a setting in Settings.settings

Tags: c#, winforms, configurationmanager

**EDIT**

I've changed my use of the setting from

```
private int _Capacity = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FuelTankCapacity"];
```

to...

```
private int _Capacity = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FuelTankCapacity"]);
```

This solved the problem, however it feels like a lazy fix. There has to be a way to specify an integer type for settings, hasn't there?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

Having created a few settings in my winforms application, I'm having some trouble with one of them.

The setting is meant to specify the maximum capacity of a fuel tank, the value being `2000` (2000 liters).

Unfortunately, the setting is being read as a string value instead of an int even though I specified it should be an integer value.

Here's the `App.config` code for this setting:

```
<setting name="FuelTankCapacity" serializeAs="String">
    <value>2000</value>
</setting>
```

Note that changing the `SerializeAs` value to **int/Int32** doesn't fix the problem.
[image: Here's the Settings.settings screen]

Comment: cannot reproduce your problem up to now, can you post a screenshot of the properties settings mask? with the variable in question?

Comment: Do you use the settings like this way: **Properties.Settings.Default.FuelTankCapacity** ?

Comment: Have you trued adding a settings file via the project properties window rather than a direct entry into the app.config.That always seems to work. You then access it via the "Properties" namespace.

Comment: @Wheels73 that's exactly how I did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is that `AppSettings` is of type `NameValueCollection` which is according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection(v=vs.110).aspx)

> a collection of associated String keys and String values that can be accessed either with the key or with the index.

So taking this route you end up inevitably with a string.

Using the `Property` namespace you can access via `Settings` the variable directly and hence access the type as you have specified it:

```
int t = Properties.Settings.Default.FuelTankCapacity;
```

Here are more information about [using settings at runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx#settingscs_topic4)

> You can access the value of settings with application scope on a read-only basis, and you can read and write the values of user-scope settings. Settings are available in C# through the Properties namespace.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'm going to accept this answer not only because it addresses the conversion issue I was having, but it also gives me the correct value whereas my code above did not.

Comment: @Ortund you are very welcome. Glad I could help. Before your question I did not know that the variables could also be accessed via the `ConfigurationManager`. Good to know this way too.